# Super Compact Bresenham's Line Algorithm v2

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, graphics

I recently posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245945/super-compact-bresenhams-line-algorithm-variant) about an implementation of the Besenham's line algorithm that I wrote. I've been hard at work improving it and redoing it from the ground up. However I still can't seem to beat BLA--not sure if I'm testing wrong or if it's something else.

```
void bresenprecalc(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    // Initialization, x,y directions and horz/vert line length.
    int dx = x2 - x1, dy = y2 - y1,
        dxA = sign(dx), dyA = sign(dy),
        dxB = abs(dx), dyB = abs(dy),
        // Set case 1 by default (dyB >= dxB).
        xm=0, ym=dyA,
        yxm=dxB, xym=dyB;
    
    // Set case 1 if dxB >= dyB.
    if (dxB >= dyB) {
        xm = dxA; ym = 0;
        yxm = dyB; xym = dxB;
    }

    // Incremental error check (see Bresenhams algorithm).
    int er2 = yxm - xym,
        er = yxm - (xym>>1);
    
    // draw x1,y1 (starting pixel).
    // End when x1 OR y1 reach EOL (faster than AND).
    for(;x1!=x2 || y1!=y2;) {
        // Error check above/below the line.
        if (er >= 0) {
            // If we've crossed the line, adjust the pixel diagonally.
            x1 += dxA;
            y1 += dyA;
            er += er2;
        } else {
            // Move in primary vertical/horizontal direction of the line.
            x1 += xm;
            y1 += ym;
            er += yxm;
        }

        // draw x1,y1 (line pixel).
    }
};
```

Without Comments:

```
void bresenprecalc(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    int dx = x2 - x1, dy = y2 - y1,
        dxA = sign(dx), dyA = sign(dy),
        dxB = abs(dx), dyB = abs(dy),
        xm=0, ym=dyA,
        yxm=dxB, xym=dyB;
    
    if (dxB >= dyB) {
        xm = dxA; ym = 0;
        yxm = dyB; xym = dxB;
    }

    int er2 = yxm - xym,
        er = yxm - (xym>>1);

    // draw x1,y1 (starting pixel).
    for(;x1!=x2 || y1!=y2;) {
        if (er >= 0) {
            x1 += dxA;
            y1 += dyA;
            er += er2;
        } else {
            x1 += xm;
            y1 += ym;
            er += yxm;
        }
        // draw x1,y1 (line pixel).
    }
};
```

I honestly think I've squeezed everything out of this implementation. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I made a quick change on the loop itself to use an OR check. Seems to be quicker.

Comment: Bump. Anyone have any solutions to this?